# Excel vba how to disallow Excel converting a month name with number into date?

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
Sub test1()
MonthYear = MonthName(Right(2009, 2)) & " " & Left(2009, 2) 'locals window show "September 20"
Range("A1").Value = MonthYear '20-Sep is shown in cell A1 where the formula box is 20-09-2022
Range("A1").Value = "'" & MonthYear '---> my solution for the time being
End Sub
```

What I want is in cell A1 show *September 20* (just like in the Locals Window), as a text not a date.

What I've tried so far :

```
Sub test2()
MonthYear = "01-" & MonthName(Right(2009, 2)) & "-20" & Left(2009, 2) 'locals window show "01-September-2020"

Range("A1").Value = MonthYear '01-Sep-20 is shown in cell A1 where the formula box is 01-09-2020

Range("A2").Value = Format(MonthYear, "mmmm yy") 'AGAIN, 20-Sep is shown in cell A1 where the formula box is 20-09-2022

Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mmmm yy" 'another solution for the time being
End Sub
```

My question:
How do I have to write the code, so it put the result in the cell directly as a text *September 20* ?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply text formatting first:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A1").Value = MonthYear
```